# Regular Expression to match IP address + wildcard

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to use a RegularexpressionValidator to match an IP address (with possible wildcards) for an IP filtering system.

I'm using the following Regex:

```
"([0-9]{1,3}\\.|\\*\\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\\*){1}"
```

Which works fine when running it in LINQPad with Regex.Matches, but doesn't seem to work when I'm using the validator.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to either a better Regex or why it would work in test but not in situ?

Cheers, Ed

Comment: Can you provide some test cases where it fails to match properly?

Comment: @VeeArr I've yet to get it to validate correctly, so any arbitrary string, including IP addresses :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asp:RegularExpressionValidator` does not require you to double-escape backslashes. You should try:

`([0-9]{1,3}\.|\*\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\*){1}`

Answer (score 4):

This: `\\.|\\*\\.` looks like the dodgy bit. Do this instead:

```
@"^(([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\*)$"
```

And to only accept 0-255 (thanks, [apoorv020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999282/regular-expression-to-match-ip-address-wildcard/2999421#2999421)):

```
^((([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\*)\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\*)$
```

Comment: Another good suggestion, but I'm afraid that doesn't work either!

Comment: It does - try it at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ . Make sure you have an `@` in front of the string. If it still doesn't work, show us the code you are using to match it. Note i'm trying to match it to things like `192.168.*.* and `10.*.*.*` - is this what you want? Can you show us some test cases?

Comment: I don't think you read my question quite right: My original Regex will match an IPv4 address with wildcards no worries, but it won't work in an asp:RegularExpressionValidator. Your Regex has exactly the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried your original regex, but replacing the escaped backslash `\\` with a regular one `\` (without using the C# `@` escape character)? (i.e. try `^(([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\*)$` or `(([0-9]{1,3}|\*)\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\*)`)

Comment: @VeeArr we have a winner. Always forget you don't have to escape in the Regex validators! Cheers, you should put that as a seperate answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

[0-9]{1,3} would allow IP addresses of the form 999.999.999.999 . Your IP address range should allow only 0-255. 
Replace all occurences of [0-9]{1,3} with 
([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]) 
This does seem very complicated to me, and probably there are better ways of doing this, but it seems correct at first glance.

Comment: I'm not massively fussed about the actual IP address being valid, only the format (it's easier to parse later), but point taken.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting start and end string characters on the expression

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\\.|\\*\\.){3}([0-9]{1,3}|\\*){1}$
```

Comment: Nice suggestion but I'm afraid that still doesn't validate!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is general for .NET, not `RegularExpressionValidator`-specific.

Regex string for IP matching (use `ExplicitCapture` to avoid useless capturing and keep RE concise):

```
"\\b0*(2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d)|1?\\d{1,2})(\\.0*(2(5[0-5]|[0-4]\\d)|1?\\d{1,2})){3}\\b"
```

Depending on particular use case you may want to add appropriate anchors, i.e. `\A` or `^` at the beginning and `\Z` or `$` at the end. Then you can remove word-boundaries requirement: `\b`.

(Remember about doubling `\` inside the string)