# Rails 3: Validate IP String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, ip-address

In Rails 3, is there a built in method for seeing if a string is a valid IP address?

If not, what is the easiest way to validate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check whether a value in a string is an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634998/how-do-i-check-whether-a-value-in-a-string-is-an-ip-address)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Rails way to validate with ActiveRecord in Rails 3 is:

```
@ip_regex = /^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/

validates :gateway, 
          :presence => true, 
          :uniqueness => true,
          :format => { :with => @ip_regex }
```

Good resource here: [Wayback Archive - Email validation in Ruby On Rails 3 or Active model without regexp](https://web.archive.org/web/20160907124743/http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/)

Answer (score 72):

Just wanted to add that instead of writing your own pattern you can use the build in one `Resolv::AddressRegex`

```
require 'resolv'

validates :gateway, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true,
  :format => { :with => Resolv::AddressRegex }
```

`Resolv::AddressRegex` matches both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. If you need only one version you can use `Resolv::IPv4::Regex` or `Resolv::IPv6::Regex`.

Comment: Not sure when they added this feature, but this is so much easier

Comment: Yes this is considerably easier. @Dex it's been around since at least ruby 1.9.2

Comment: I can confirm [it's in Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv/IPv4.html)

Comment: This is a very nice and clean solution. Works fine with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2

Comment: Just want to note here that there's also the `Resolv::AddressRegex` expression, which permits both IPv4 & IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just call standard's library `IPAddr.new` that will parse **subnets**, **IPV6** and other cool things: ([IPAddr](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html))  and return `nil` if the format was wrong.

Just do:

```
valid = !(IPAddr.new('192.168.2.0/24') rescue nil).nil?  
#=> true

valid = !(IPAddr.new('192.168.2.256') rescue nil).nil?  
#=> false
```

Comment: Way better solution than the accepted answer with the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Resolv::IPv4::Regex` as Jack mentioned below if you don't need to accept subnets.

If you need to accept it, [activemodel-ipaddr_validator](https://rubygems.org/gems/activemodel-ipaddr_validator) gem may help you. (disclaimer: I'm the author of the gem)

```
validates :your_attr, ipaddr: true
```

Comment: Works well. Maybe worth adding the disclaimer that it is _your_ gem.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about RoR a lot, but if you dont find any built in method for validation of IP Address.

Try on this regular expression :

```
"^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$"
```

to validate the IP Address.

I recently used it in one module so had it on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Regular Expression`

Here is one that does what you want:

```
/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.
([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/.match("#{@systemIP}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Regexy::Web::IPv4](https://github.com/vladimir-tikhonov/regexy#regexywebipv4) which can match ip addresses with port numbers too.