# Rails - Validate Expressions [X or Y]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation

I have defined 2 regular expressions.

```
ip_regex = /^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/
hostname_regex = /^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/
```

I need to allow users to input either an IP address or a Hostname in to a textfield. My validation code is as follows.

```
validates :ip_address,  :presence => true,
                        :format   => { :with => ip_regex || hostname_regex }
```

I've verified that the ip_regex is successful. However, the hostname_regex isn't. It appears that either the hostname_regex or my validation code is flawed. Which is it? How do I resolve this issue? Is there a more effective &/or efficient way of performing this task?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3756184/297323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nothing wrong with your hostname_regex.

You can use regular expression OR(|) operator to match more than one format.Just seperate regular expressions by | operator.

```
validates :ip_address,  :presence => true,
:format   => { :with =>/(^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$)|(^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$)/ }
```

Refer

Comment: This worked perfectly. Your assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

-> http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/