# IP address format check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Ruby on Rails** application by using **Ruby v1.8.7** . My question is more about **Ruby** language.

I know there is a build-in Ruby library named [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) in **Ruby v1.8.7** . It handles IP address related issues well. But, seems it does not provide any method to check IP address format.

Could someone provide me **a good way to check IP address format**(IPv4 and IPv6 addresses) in Ruby? Thank you.

**P.S.**

I tried a regular expression way:

```
ip_regex = ^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$

ip_addr='127.0.0.3'
ip_addr =~ ip_regex
```

But it does not work...

Comment: You need to fix your regular expression `ip_regex = /^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$/`

Comment: @taro, can you answer the question instead of comment, so that I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your regular expression is wrong.
It should be:

```
/^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$/
```

Answer (score 6):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html

The IPAddr class already provides methods to check whether they're IPV4 or IPV6 formats:

- #ipv4?
- #ipv6?

Comment: I'd recommend this method, it supports both IP4 and IP6 type addresses, and won't break on you in the future.

Comment: ActiveValidators, as mentioned by Damien, relies on IPAddr, so it's really up to whether or not you want to use a gem for that (which does plenty of other validations).

Comment: Something to keep in mind here is that those methods only work on an instance of the IPAddr class.  So, if a non-IP value was suppplied like "300.300.300.300", you'd end up with an Argument error before you could use those methods.

Answer (score 3):

[ActiveValidators](https://github.com/cesario/activevalidators/blob/master/lib/active_model/validations/ip_validator.rb) has an IP validator.
It uses a regex for any ipv4, and `Resolv::IPv6::Regex` for any ipv6 address.

To use it, it's very simple.
Add activevalidators to your Gemfile.

```
gem 'activevalidators'
```

Then, in your Computer class :

```
class Computer << ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :remote_address,
    :ip => { :format => :v4 }
end
```

Comment: If I have a model class computer << ActiveRecord, how to use this validtor?

Comment: Hi, I am developing a Rails v2.3.2 app. Seems the activevalidators only support Rails v3 ... Because I add the gem and run bundle install, it complains about my activerecord version

Comment: Well, yeah, it is only rails3. You can still get the regex and use it in your rails2 app. Or (even better), upgrade !

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :ip,
      :format => {
        :with => Regexp.union(Resolv::IPv4::Regex, Resolv::IPv6::Regex)
      }
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157862/378006