# Regular expression to validate IPv4 address in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to verify whether a given string is valid IPv4 address or not in ruby.
I tried as follows but what is does is matches values greater than 255 as well.
How to limit each block's range from 0-255

```
str="255.255.255.256"
if str=~ /\b[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\b/
puts true
else
puts false
end
```

Comment: Or if you really want to stick with regexp solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
block = /\d{,2}|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]/
re = /\A#{block}\.#{block}\.#{block}\.#{block}\z/

re =~ "255.255.255.255" # => 0
re =~ "255.255.255.256" # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sawa. Your answer helped me understand regex in a much better way. Finally i created a new regex on my own.

Comment: Why are you changing the regex? Yours is wrong; it does not accept `"199"` as a block. Also, explicitly returning a boolean value is a bad idea. If you want to convert the result into a boolean, do `!!` to the result.

Comment: yes, i was wrong, thnx again.

Comment: Does not work :( - re =~ '192.168.0.74' => nil

Comment: @RomanGaufman Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: There is a Problem with Ruby 2.5.1 ```> re =~ ".255.255.255"
=> 0``` it returs 0, but it shouldn't

Answer (score 15):

You have the [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class in Ruby. You do not need to validate it agains a regex, just create a new object and catch the exception when it fails:

```
require 'ipaddr'

ip = IPAddr.new "127.0.0.1"
# => #<IPAddr: IPv4:127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255>

ip = IPAddr.new "127.0.0.a"
# => IPAddr::InvalidAddressError: invalid address
```

Comment: Actually just catching this exception is not enough to ensure you have an IPv4 address, you also need to check `ip.ipv4?` returns `true`. Consider the example given in the docs: `IPAddr.new "3ffe:505:2::1"`. This does not raise an exception, as it is a valid IPv6 address.

Answer (score 8):

You'd better to use ruby core class `IPAddress`

you could do it this way:

```
 require "ipaddress"

 IPAddress.valid? "192.128.0.12"
 #=> true

 IPAddress.valid? "192.128.0.260"
 #=> false
```

you could find more here [How do I check whether a value in a string is an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634998/how-do-i-check-whether-a-value-in-a-string-is-an-ip-address)

Comment: I don't want to use inbuilt function.

Comment: Actually [ipaddress](https://rubygems.org/gems/ipaddress) is a gem, not a core class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way that reads pretty easily:

```
str.count('.')==3 && str.split('.').all? {|s| s[/^\d{3}$/] && s.to_i < 256}
```