# inet_aton() returning success for invalid ip addresses?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, ip

I am looking for some function to verify that if given string is a valid ipv4 address,
but inet_aton() seems to be happy with strings like "11" and "1.1"
what is best way to validate an ipv4 string.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct in_addr addr;

   if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s <dotted-address>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   if (inet_aton(argv[1], &addr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid address\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

the ouput for some invalid strings are

```
[root@ ~]# ./a.out 1.1
1.0.0.1
[root@ ~]# ./a.out "1 some junk"
0.0.0.1
[root@ ~]# ./a.out "10 some junk"
0.0.0.10
```

I want a routine to reject any string not in dotted decimal notation
x.x.x.x, x from 0 to 255

Comment: You can check this post to validate an ipv4 string.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791982/determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-ip-address-in-c

Comment: `1.1` is a valid ip4 address which means `1.0.0.1`

Comment: inet_aton is behaving as described in its manpage http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton

Comment: @Ozan thanks, MM is "1" and "1 abc" also valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the specified/documented behavior for `inet_aton`.

If you want to accept only dotted-quad decimal notation, use:

```
unsigned char *a = (void *)&addr, dummy;
if (sscanf(src, "%3hhd.%3hhd.%3hhd.%3hhd%c", a, a+1, a+2, a+3, &dummy)!=4) {
    /* error */
}
```

Alternatively, you might use the `inet_pton` function, which is more restrictive in the formats it accepts.