# Converting IP address char to long

Tags: c, long-integer

I wrote a small program to convert a char to a long, however when I try to print the char form, it has mangled output.

```
int main()
{
    long l;
    char *buf = "127.0.0.1";
    memcpy(&l, buf, sizeof(long));
    printf("%s\n", (char *)&l);

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

> 127.0.0.t�턾U

I know I'm missing something simple but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: There's a lot of undefined behavior here. You're basically just copying the first 8 characters into a long slot and printing a non-null-terminated char pointer. There is no conversion into a long happening really, and it's fortunate that the print-out doesn't keep going. I suggest that you read a primer on C--perhaps the K&R book.

Comment: Everything is wrong there, you better go back to your C book and come back when you understand a little more of how all of that works.

Comment: [Here's a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327077).

Comment: The thing you are missing is that this isn't supposed to work.

Comment: I don't see any code to convert anything. I see code that tries to copy a string into something that's supposed to hold a long and then something that tries to print a string from something that holds a long. Where is the code to actually *convert* anything?

Answer (score 3):

Seems as if there are some basic misunderstandings :-)

Copying between `char *` and `long` data type does not convert a "number" represented by a sequence of digits into a "binary" number like long; neither does a cast from `long` to `char *` do the opposite in your `printf`-statement.

Converting `char*` to long is done using `atol`, whereas printing a long to console is done through `printf("%ld",l)`

Good luck and patience on your way to get an experienced C programmer, and don't hesitate to ask :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program that takes an IP address in the form of an input string, and converts it to a `long` value. The `filter_ip()` function is used to first remove all non-numeric characters from the string. Then `strtol()` is used to convert the string to a `long` value.

It is better to use `strtol()` than `atol()` because `strtol()` detects integer overflows. `errno` is declared in the `error.h` header file, and `strtol()` sets the value of `errno` if there is an overflow. `strtol()` converts as many characters as it can, starting from the beginning of the string, and sets `tailptr` to point the the remaining characters. If no conversion can be performed, `tailptr` will point to the beginning of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

void filter_ip(char *str);

int main(void)
{
    char ip_addr[] = "127.0.0.1";
    long res;
    char *tailptr;

    printf("IP Address: %s\n", ip_addr);
    filter_ip(ip_addr);

    errno = 0;
    res = strtol(ip_addr, &tailptr, 10);
    if (errno) {
        perror("Unable to convert IP address");
    } else if (tailptr == ip_addr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No conversion performed\n");
    } else {
        printf("%ld\n", res);
    }

    return 0;
}

void filter_ip(char *str)
{
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit(str[i])) {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
}
```

Program output:

```
IP Address: 127.0.0.1
127001
```